# Operations on $\operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right)$

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces

I'm reading *Difference Operators and Summation Formulas* from textbook Analysis I by Amann/Escher.

> [image]

The authors omit some detail and I would like to verify whether my understanding is correct or not.

> Let $E$ be a vector space over field $\mathbb{K}$. To simplify notation, we write ${\operatorname{G}f}_n$ for $(\operatorname{G}(f))_n$ where $\operatorname{G} \in \operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right)$ and $f \in E^{\mathbb{N}}$.
>
> On $E^{\mathbb{N}}$ define operators $\triangle, \operatorname{I}, \operatorname{O}$ by $$\triangle f_{n} :=f_{n+1}-f_{n} \text{ and } \operatorname{I} f_{n} := f_{n} \text{ and } \operatorname{O} f_{n} := 0$$
>
> It is easy to verify that $\triangle, \operatorname{I} ,\operatorname{O} \in \operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right)$.
>
> On $\operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right)$ define addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$ by $$(\operatorname{G} + \operatorname{H})f_n := {\operatorname{G}f}_n + {\operatorname{H}f}_n \text{ and } (\operatorname{G} \cdot \operatorname{H})f := \operatorname{G} (\operatorname{H}f), \quad G,H \in \operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right)$$
>
> As such, $\left \langle \operatorname{End}\left(E^{\mathbb{N}}\right), +, \cdot \right \rangle$ is a (not necessarily commutative) ring with unity. More specifically, $\operatorname{I}$ is the multiplicative identity and $\operatorname{O}$ the additive identity of this ring. As such, $\triangle \cdot \operatorname{I} = \operatorname{I} \cdot \triangle$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, looks good.  You can go further to say that $\operatorname{End}(E^{\mathbb{N}})$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It is generally true that if $V$ is a vector space over $K$, that $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is a ring with identity over $K.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood correctly ! As stated in the comments (if you know what that means) $(\lambda\cdot G) f_n := \lambda Gf_n$ also defines a $\mathbb K$-algebra structure on $\mathrm{End}(E^\mathbb N)$.

In fact this works for any vector space $V$, not just for $E^\mathbb N$